# Python Palindrome Try and Except not printing

Tags: python

My except won't print when `len(line.strip()) == d` gets `None`.

```
def isPalindrome(word):
    if len(word) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        if word[0] == word[-1]:
            return isPalindrome(word[1:-1])
        else:
            return False

def fileInput(filename):
    palindromes = False
    fh = open(filename, "r")
    length = input("Enter length of palindromes:")
    d = int(length)
    try:
        for line in fh:
            for s in str(len(line)):
                if isPalindrome(line.strip()):
                    palindromes = True
                    if (len(line.strip()) == d):
                        print(line.strip())
    except:
        print("No palindromes found for length entered.")
    finally:
        fh.close()
```

Comment: Can you edit your code to make it more readable? Try using the "code" button in the text editor

Comment: Can you show what the file input looks like?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MMnBErDB

Answer (score 2):

Your code is failing because your exception is not the only place where non-existence of d-length palindromes in your input file takes you.
You need to check for the value of `palindromes` as well.

So, at the end of your try-block, add a line that prints `"no palindromes found"`, like so:

```
def fileInput(filename):
  palindromes = False
  # more code
  try:
    # more code
    if not palindromes:
      print("No palindromes found for length entered.")
  except:
    print("No palindromes found for length entered.")
  finally:
    # more code
```

By the way, I would clean up your function as follows:

```
def isPalindrome(word):
  if not len(word):  # is the same as len(word) == 0
    return True
  elif word[0] == word[-1]:  # no need for overly nested if-else-blocks
    return isPalindrome(word[1:-1])
  else:
    return False

def fileInput(filename):
  palindromes = False
  d = int(input("Enter length of palindromes:"))
  with open(filename) as fh:  # defaults to "r" mode. Also, takes care of closing the file for you
    for line in fh:
      word = line.strip()
      if isPalindrome(word) and len(word) == d:  # note that you didn't have the len(word)==d check before. Without that, you don't check for the length of the palindrome
        palindromes = True
        print(word)
    if not palindromes:
      print("No palindromes found for length entered.")
```

Comment: That worked just fine except i get an un ending list of "No palindromes found for length entered." when I just want it printed once

Comment: @user3040301: I suspect you may be mixing tabs and spaces. Try fixing the indentation of your code and run it again. This code shouldn't print that multiple times